# ListDensityPlot with discrete values and colors

Tags: plotting, color

I have a file with mesh points and a value that indicates the domain the point belongs to

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ll9hb3oxxreufsg/AABvU7nufHhyHY3W4ausanJ6a?dl=0

I would like to plot using `DensityPlot` and showing the mesh in different colors (assuming two domains) according to the domain by using MeshShading

```
data = Import["https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ll9hb3oxxreufsg/AAA6hJL-suwY6MSslRtuSE7Fa/mesh_and_domain.txt?dl=1", "Table"];

n = Max[data[[;; , 3]]];
domidx = Range[n];
color = {RGBColor[1, 0, 0], RGBColor[0, 0, 1]};
dom = Table[Select[data, #[[3]] == idx &], {idx, domidx}];
Show @@
 {Table[
   ListDensityPlot[dom[[idx]], Mesh -> All, InterpolationOrder -> 1, 
    MeshShading -> color[[idx]]], {idx, domidx}],
  PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 0.5}
```

[image]

However MeshShading is not accepted as an option for `ListDensityPlot`

Do you have some idea how to solve it?

Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: Replace `MeshShading` with `MeshStyle`?

Comment: That changes the color of the mesh lines, I would like to control the color corresponding to the "density", I guess is the shading or at least a kind of piecewise colorfunction

Comment: So the density plot is just flat, since the third value of each element is the same.  Do you want a black mesh on top of a solid color, which is different for the two domains?  If that's the case, you could replace your `MeshShading` option with `ColorFunction -> (color[[idx]] &)`

Comment: Oh yeah, that is working!

Answer (score 4):

With just a slight modification to your code,

```
Show @@ {Table[
   ListDensityPlot[dom[[idx]], Mesh -> All, InterpolationOrder -> 1, 
    ColorFunction -> (color[[idx]] &)], {idx, domidx}], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 0.5}
```

[image]

Or you can use a custum color function

```
ListDensityPlot[data, 
 ColorFunction -> (Which[#1 == 1, Red, #1 == 2, Blue] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, InterpolationOrder -> 1, 
 AspectRatio -> 0.5, Mesh -> All]
```

[image]

I like the plot better with `InterpolationOrder -> 0`, but then it draws the mesh differently (around the points rather than through them)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can do it without generating all these variables.

Download data, notice the direct link, easier that way.

```
data = Import["https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ll9hb3oxxreufsg/AAA6hJL-suwY6MSslRtuSE7Fa/mesh_and_domain.txt?dl=1", "Table"]
```

Separate using `GatherBy[data, Last]` ([`GatherBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html)).

Change colours using the index of [`MapIndexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html),to  [`RotateLeft`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RotateLeft.html) the list `{0,0,1}` and use as argument for [`RGBColor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RGBColor.html)

```
Show[
 MapIndexed[
  ListDensityPlot[#1
    , Mesh -> All
    , InterpolationOrder -> 1
    , ColorFunction -> 
     Function[z, RGBColor[RotateLeft[{0, 0, 1}, Last[#2]]]]
    ] &,
  GatherBy[data, Last]
  ], PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 0.5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you have more than three colours, probably you could use `Hue[#2/n]` ([`Hue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hue.html))

Comment: Thanks for the comment about the direct link, I had used OP's link and it downloaded an html file

Comment: Very interesting solution using GatherBy, thanks!